# Caps Lock for Numeric Keys

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, key-binding

Is there a way I can have persistent access to the special characters above the numeric keys?  I'm thinking something akin to the <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> key but that locks the numeric keys to the equivalent <kbd>Shift</kbd> + number combination.  For example when I press the <kbd>3</kbd> key I would get a <kbd>#</kbd> instead.  I'm not looking to install any 3rd party software for this, but rather I'm looking for some function built-in to either all keyboards or the OS.

Comment: ..What OS are you using?

Comment: If you are using Windows sounds like someone might actually get to use from [StickyKeys](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/access_stickykeys_settings.mspx?mfr=true). Once enabled hit shift twice to lock shift. Tested on Windows 7 x64

Comment: @Matt I've been nothing but annoyed by StickeyKeys but this sounds like a legitimate use. Usually I just end up trying to brainstorm and forget I'm in mid-sentence holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and spend the next 5 mins trying to turn it off.

Comment: @Raystafarian - Windows. Updated tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can enable ease of access functions to allow toggling status for SHIFT or CONTROL.